# Retreiving info from another layer

Tags: qgis, aggregate

I have two shapefiles:

1. street (polyline) listing of all streets in one village
   with fields 'streetId', 'Streetlength' (virtual field)
2. streetpanel listing of all panels displaying street name
   with fields 'panelid' , 'streetref' making a reference to the streetid of table 1

I want to put in table 2 a calculated field that retrieves the street length the panel refers to.

I am not a real expert in QGIS/Python, so I looked at what I can do with existing functions (`getfeature()`, `attributes()`, `aggregate()`,...) but I do not know how to address this.

How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layer 1 is called `street`, its id being `streetid` and has a column `streetlength`

Layer 2 has a field called `streetref`, refering to the `streetid` in Layer1

Add a computed column with this code in Layer2:

`attributes(get_feature('street','streetid', "streetref" ))['streetlength']`

Gets the feature from layer `street` where attribute `streetid` is equal to `"streetref"` (from Layer2)

And gets the `streetlength` attribute from that feature

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this idea, I will work on it and will give you a feedback

Comment: Great, you might want to accept the Answer then :). Merci!

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)